# offsetWidth different when inside DIV vs TD

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using primeng with angular, However, it feels like my problem is with html/css.

I have found out how to present my ui the way I would like with the datatable component. However, when I leverage the datatable component inside the rowexpansion feature my column widths are not adhered to.

You will see that in the below table inside a table the column width is 100px. The parent table has it correctly set to 100px.

Here is the entry code [entry](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/datatable/datatable.ts#L2102)

[Here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/datatable/datatable.ts#L2227) is where the width of the columns are set

Specifically the code that I debugged is below

```
for(let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
   columns[i].style.width = columns[i].offsetWidth + 'px';
}
```

[image]

The `offsetWidth` is different for the parent then the child even though I am setting the style the same way for both tables.

My conclusion thus far is that `offsetWidth` is calculated differently when my table is inside a `div` vs inside of a `td`.

I looked at the default css for each HTML element and tried to make them match. However, it must be displayed as a `table-cell` because it requires the `colspan` attribute otherwise the row won't span the table as intended.

I have looked at a number of websites to determine how `offsetWidth` is calculated but nothing has stood out to me. So I am going to the SO community to see if there is a bug in the browser (Chrome) or if there is a css property I can use to make it behave the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The offsetWidth and offsetHeight returns the element's layout width and height.
It includs the width of the visible content, scrollbars (if any), padding, and border.
[Read more here...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements)

Table has a **cellspacing** property which is used by the **TD** tag. This **cellspacing** is not considered in **offsetWidth** or **offsetHeight**. Aside div tag has no **cellspacing** property.

Below example will clear/solve your problem.

```js
var a = document.getElementById('div');
var b = document.getElementById('tda');
var log = document.getElementById('log');

//Border+Padding+ClientWidth
log.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","Div offset: "+a.offsetWidth);
log.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","<br />Table offset: "+b.offsetWidth);
log.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","<br />Table Tbody offset: "+b.children[0].offsetWidth);
log.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","<br />Table TR offset: "+b.children[0].children[0].offsetWidth);

//Border+Padding+ClientWidth, Except Cell spacing
log.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","<br />Table TD offset: "+ b.children[0].children[0].children[0].offsetWidth);
```

```css
#tda {width:400px}
#div{width:100px;border: 1px solid red}
```

```html
<div id="div">DIV</div>

<table id="tda" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="6">
  <tr>
    <td>TD</td>
    <td>TD</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

Comment: How does this tell me why the offset is different for `td` vs `div`

Comment: sorry @Pradeep but this did not help me. I know about those additional attributes but they were not being used in my tables. Also I didn't understand how this makes the when the width is identical between the `td` and the `div`. Based on the answer I provided, I suspect the browser handles content width different when the container is a `td` vs a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

So I still don't know why I get different results between `div` and `td`.

However, looking [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) I was able to find the width property that does the same thing as `auto`, in my case, called `max-content`. When I set this CSS width property value on my table, I get the same result in the child as in the parent. See screenshot below:

[image]

Again I don't know why auto gives me different results for the child and the parent table but I found a workaround.

In case someone else is still interested, the best information I found for this so far was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2398079/2038176).